# RSAM error: Long transaction detected informix

Tags: transactions, informix

I am using JDBC API for inserting more then 190 000 rows into table in informix database. First, I set connection autocommit to false and I am making connection commit on every 1000th row. However I got this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Long transaction aborted.
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3494)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3807)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2610)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2526)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.j(IfxSqli.java:2197)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.getaRow(IfxSqli.java:4525)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.next(IfxResultSet.java:526)
at etaxarchive.FillDataManager.insertIntoTable(FillDataManager.java:173)
at etaxarchive.FillDataManager.fillTableData(FillDataManager.java:129)
at etaxarchive.ETaxArchiveManager.insertDataInArchiveTables(ETaxArchiveManager.java:224)
at etaxarchive.ETaxArchiveManager.archiveData(ETaxArchiveManager.java:97)
at etaxarchive.ETaxArchive.main(ETaxArchive.java:38)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: RSAM error: Long transaction detected.
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3812)
... 10 more
```

Can anybody has an idea about this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can talk with db admin and suggest to increase log size. You can also try with smaller amounts of rows in one transaction: 500, 200 or even 100. Smaller transactions can work faster -- try to tune it with db admin.

More information: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=256031